# Form's OnNotifyMessage being blocked by user control

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I'm developing a Windows Forms C# app that will work with a Smart Board. It sends special events that my form has to register to receive. This code is taken from a sample of their SDK and it works fine; I'm able to receive the special OnXYDown (etc) events that tell me when someone is drawing on the board with a pen.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ISBSDKBaseClass2_4 Sbsdk;
    private _ISBSDKBaseClass2_4Events_Event SbsdkEvents;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int RegisterWindowMessageA([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpString);
    private int SBSDKMessageID;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
        SBSDKMessageID = RegisterWindowMessageA("SBSDK_NEW_MESSAGE");

        // set up smart board SDK
        try 
        {
            Sbsdk = new SBSDKBaseClass2_4();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        if (Sbsdk != null)
            SbsdkEvents = (_ISBSDKBaseClass2_4Events_Event)Sbsdk;

        if (SbsdkEvents != null)
        {
            SbsdkEvents.OnNoTool += new SBSDKComWrapperLib._ISBSDKBaseClass2_4Events_OnNoToolEventHandler(this.OnNoTool);
            SbsdkEvents.OnPen += new SBSDKComWrapperLib._ISBSDKBaseClass2_4Events_OnPenEventHandler(this.OnPen);
            SbsdkEvents.OnXYDown += new SBSDKComWrapperLib._ISBSDKBaseClass2_4Events_OnXYDownEventHandler(this.OnXYDown);
            SbsdkEvents.OnXYMove += new SBSDKComWrapperLib._ISBSDKBaseClass2_4Events_OnXYMoveEventHandler(this.OnXYMove);
            SbsdkEvents.OnXYUp += new SBSDKComWrapperLib._ISBSDKBaseClass2_4Events_OnXYUpEventHandler(this.OnXYUp);
        if (Sbsdk != null)
            Sbsdk.SBSDKAttachWithMsgWnd(Handle.ToInt32(), false, Handle.ToInt32());
    }

    int count = 0;
    protected override void OnNotifyMessage(Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == SBSDKMessageID)
        {
            // process sdk events on our apps main thread
            Console.WriteLine("notify message happened " + count++);
            Sbsdk.SBSDKProcessData();
        }
    }

    private void OnXYDown(int x, int y, int z, int iPointerID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnXYDown event (" + iPointerID + ") " + count++);
    }

    private void OnXYMove(int x, int y, int z, int iPointerID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnXYMove event " + count++);
    }

    private void OnXYUp(int x, int y, int z, int iPointerID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnXYUp event " + count++);
    }
    private void OnPen(int iPointerID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnPen event " + count++);
    }

    private void OnNoTool(int iPointerID)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnNoTool event " + count++);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I SetStyle on the parent form to allow for notify messages to be sent, then register an ID that the Smart Board will use to indicate its events. If I place the pen on the screen, a stream of "notify message happened" and "OnXY" printouts happen until I lift the pen, indicating that everything is being sent.

However, if I place a `OpenTK.GLControl` user-defined control on top of the window (my app will be drawing user strokes with OpenGL), any time the pen touches the GLControl, nothing is sent; I don't receive OnXY events, nor do I receive any message in OnNotifyMessage. This also happens if I place, say... a `Button` on screen, but not if I place certain other interface elements, like a `Panel` (the events get received in OnNotifyMessage if I draw on the panel, but not if I draw on the button). These controls seem to be blocking events from being sent to the parent form.

What is the solution to this? Am I misunderstanding what's happening here, or how the events are being raised? It seems like `SetStyle` cannot be called on any control that isn't the parent form itself, so I couldn't, say, register the GLControl to receive the events instead of the form. And because these events are special Windows messages, I don't know how to "forward" them to where they need to go.

Comment: The company has a phone number, give them a call.  1.888.42SMART

Comment: It's possible to contact the company yes, although it may not be timely to get a response. I figure this is actually a C#/Windows problem rather than a Smart board SDK problem, and I was hoping someone here would be familiar with what is causing it.